# MySQL pivot query that places field names into query results

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a MySQL table with field names that I would like to display as values in the query results.

The original result of a query such as SELECT * FROM patientTable is:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| general_preference_id                | preference_id                        | experimental_medication | only_local_patient | accepts_walkin | accepts_handicap | accepts_medicare | accepts_medicaid | accepts_newpatient |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| 0e61628c-a0d1-11e6-8b76-3f0b1a629ff3 | 00f86ce2-a0d1-11e6-8b76-3f0b1a629ff3 |                       0 |                  1 |              0 |                0 |                1 |                0 |                  1 |
| 62902706-a173-11e6-8b76-3f0b1a629ff3 | 62336a9e-a173-11e6-8b76-3f0b1a629ff3 |                       0 |                  1 |              0 |                0 |                1 |                0 |                  0 |
| 69c0333e-a0ba-11e6-8b76-3f0b1a629ff3 | 698bd636-a0ba-11e6-8b76-3f0b1a629ff3 |                       0 |                  0 |              0 |                0 |                0 |                0 |                  1 |
| 70efaa26-a0c2-11e6-8b76-3f0b1a629ff3 | 09dced0c-a0bc-11e6-8b76-3f0b1a629ff3 |                       0 |                  1 |              0 |                0 |                1 |                0 |                  0 |
| a2661d30-bd6c-11e6-9f6c-76b11f833da1 | e3ed9d28-ac9c-11e6-86fc-3a326ff3d861 |                       1 |                  0 |              1 |                0 |                1 |                0 |                  1 |
| c162a270-bbb3-11e6-bff9-8f81d6b1f1a6 | 2a903ca6-9a6e-11e6-8b76-3f0b1a629ff3 |                       0 |                  1 |              1 |                1 |                1 |                0 |                  1 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

I would like to run a query that pulled a result that is formatted like this where the field names become values in the type field/column:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| type                                 | data0                                | data1                                |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| general_preference_id                | 0e61628c-a0d1-11e6-8b76-3f0b1a629ff3 | 62902706-a173-11e6-8b76-3f0b1a629ff3 |
| preference_id                        | 00f86ce2-a0d1-11e6-8b76-3f0b1a629ff3 | 62336a9e-a173-11e6-8b76-3f0b1a629ff3 |
| experimental_medication              | 0                                    | 0                                    |
| only_local_patient                   | 1                                    | 1                                    |
| accepts_walkin                       | 0                                    | 0                                    |
| accepts_handicap                     | 0                                    | 0                                    |
| accepts_medicare                     | 1                                    | 1                                    |
| accepts_medicaid                     | 0                                    | 0                                    |
| accepts_newpatient                   | 1                                    | 1                                    |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this result set on your front end tool whatever you use but if you want this in Mysql result set then you have to achieve this goal by using complex query of cursor in mysql.

Comment: Please provide a code sample / additional information resources when posting an answer.